# Latex - Nomenclature for a thesis when you have multiple chapters

Tags: latex, terminology, pdflatex, texstudio

I am writing my PhD thesis, and I have multiple chapters where I compile a list of tables, figures and references. However, I struggle to put my "List of Symbols", as I need to call them from multiple chapters. Their order is not very important at the moment, so a general list should be fine (i.e. I don't need to group symbols chapter by chapter).

When I use the following commands in one of the chapters (for example), nothing happens.
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass (kg)}
\printnomenclature

If you have a template or know how to make this work, it would be highly appreciated.

My code structure is as the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\include{thesis.preamble} % where all packages are embedded.
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}


% -------------------------------------------
% [-] Title Page
% -------------------------------------------
\title{title of the study}

\normallinespacing
\maketitle
\preface
\input{prefaces/abstract}
\input{prefaces/acknowledgements}


% -------------------------------------------
% [-] Main Body 
% -------------------------------------------

\body
% [-] Introduction
\input{body/chapter1}
% chapters in between.
% [-] Conclusion
\input{body/chapter8}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Using package nomencl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27824/using-package-nomencl) seems to be what you are looking for. The comments infer to be cautious about the ordering of the commands.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that does not rely on your local files we don't have access to?